# Interface minimises reusability and maintainability

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

I read that inheritance should be used only if you want to use the overriding facility.  Interfaces and composition should be used if you only use inheritance for code sharing.  Have a look at the code below:

```
Public Class Animal
    Public Overridable Sub Eat()
        MsgBox("Animal Eat no arguement")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Horse
    Inherits Animal
    Public Overrides Sub Eat()
        MsgBox("Horse Eat no arguement")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Horse inherits from Animal and overrides Eat.  This is a valid use of inheritance based on what I read.  Now say you add a Cat class and a Dog class that inherit from animnal.  Now say that Horse; Cat and Dog use the Eat function from the Animal class (instead of overriding it) then this is an invalid use of inheritance based on what I read (interfaces shouod be used).  Surely if you use interfaces i.e. IEatable to implement the Eat interface then Eat has to be written in every class, which minimizes reuseability and maintainability.  What am I missing here?

Update
After reading the responses I believe I can do something like this:

```
 Public Class Animal
    Public Overridable Sub Eat()
        MsgBox("Animal Eat no arguement")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Fish
    Inherits Animal
    Implements ISwim
    Private s1 As New Swim
    Public Sub Swim() Implements ISwim.Swim
        s1.Swim()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Shark
    Inherits Animal
    Implements ISwim
    Private s1 As New Swim
    Public Sub Swim() Implements ISwim.Swim
        s1.Swim()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Elephant

End Class

Public Class Swim
    Public Sub Swim()
        MsgBox("Animal can swim")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Interface ISwim
    Sub Swim()
End Interface
```

In the above code, two of the three animals implement ISwim and use composition to provide an implementation of Swim.  Is this a valid approach?

Comment: If the base class `Animal` implements the interface `IEater`, then every class deriving from `Animal` implements the interface `IEater` and the interface method `IEater.Eat` in the same way with no additional code. This does not restrict you from implementing `IEater.Eat` in a different way in some more-derived class, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use inheritance for the implementation of `Eat` if you can use the same code for all, or some, of the classes. If you need different implementations for some classes, you can make it virtual and use the implementation from `Animal` in any class that doesn't specifically have a different implementation.

You would use an interface if you have different implementations for all classes, or if you want to add the ability to only some of the clases. The `ISwim` interface would for example only be implemented by some animals.

Comment: Pretty much writing the same things in parallel :)

Comment: Thanks.  If you have a function called swim, then were would you put this? Assume that one of the classes that derive from Animal can swim (fish) and three cannot (elephant, monkey and Dog).

Comment: @w0051977: I would put it in an interface, as some of the animals doesn't have the ability at all.

Comment: Thanks, but that would mean that the same code is entered into multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with what I believe is an answer. Do you agree with what I have said?

Comment: @w0051977: The theory is right, but you haven't used an interface at all. You have made it a class and encapsulated instances of it in the animal classes that use it. If you would use an interface, then you can cast a `Fish` or `Shark` instance to `ISwim`, and use the same code to make either swim. With your current code you would need one piece of code to make the fish swim, and another piece of code to make the shark swim, and you would have to add more and more code for any additional aminal that could swim.

Comment: Thanks.  I have made a further change to the update based on your last comment.  What do you think now, please? +1 by the way.

Comment: Is this a common pattern (last question)?

Comment: Yes, using interfaces to add abilities to classes is frequently used in the framework, for example the `IEnumerable<T>` interface. To use a common class for the implemetnation is not as common, as the classes usually are so different that they need separate implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance should be used to model an [`IS-A`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. Since `Horse` is a type of  `Animal` it makes perfect sense to inherit here -- and code reuse does not come into the discussion.

Most of the time many types of animals share common behavior so you see the code sharing in action. But shared implementation is the *consequence* of the hierarchy correctly modelling the problem domain, not the *reason* to inherit.

When you have many types of animals that share a default implementation, provide that implementation in the base class `Animal`. When there is no obvious implementation that applies to most animals (or when you want to force creators of animals to explicitly state how they want the behavior to be implemented), use an abstract function. When there are unrelated types of objects that share similar behavior (e.g. an aeroplane and a sparrow can both fly) and when not all types of animal exhibit a given behavior, it makes sense to describe the common behavior with an interface (e.g. `IFlightCapable`).

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the statement: " consequence of the hierarchy correctly modelling the problem domain, not the reason to inherit."

Comment: Thanks. If you have a function called run, then were would you put this? Assume that three of the classes that derive from Animal can run and one cannot

Comment: @w0051977: Either in a `LeggedAnimal` class (if it makes sense, not sure with only three child classes) or in an `ILeggedCreature` interface. You might also have both: `LeggedAnimal implements ILeggedCreature`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated my question with what I believe is an answer.  Do you agree with what I have said?